# Text box in a navigation drawer in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am looking to customize the navigation drawer menu in the default Navigation Template in Android Studio. I want to add a Text box in it.
Here is the code. Where do i add it? And how?

activity_mail.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />


</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add another entry to your `NavigationDrawer`, you can just add another `item` entry to your `activity_main_drawer` XML like so:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/unique_id_for_your_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/path_to_your_icon_if_any"
        android:title="Your Title" />
```

Comment: I am able to add items. I want to add a text box so that i can enter some value, which is not possible using <item />.

Answer (score 0):

guy, I tried this and worked:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nvTeste"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       >
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:text="apenas teste"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: already tried. this doesn't work. Error:(24) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)